# Client Certificate Authentication Error: "System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

Tags: c#, client-certificates

Sending a https request using authentication by a **client certificate** from a .Net appclication results in a "System.IO.IOException: **Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream" error**.

The same request with t**he same client certificate works with postman and also with curl**.

The same .Net application **works in other environments**.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var url = "https://yyyyyyyy:8081/xxxxxxxxx;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import("zzzzzz.pfx");
if (!cert.HasPrivateKey) throw new Exception("Certificate has no private key");
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
if (request.ClientCertificates.Count != 1) throw new Exception("Certificate not loaded");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
// Bumm!!
```

Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Comment: What happens if you have a look in the `Response` property of the `WebException`? That may give you the exact error that the server is producing

Comment: Are you running your application with the correct privileges? Have you tried running it under administrator rights?

Comment: @Martin: I do not get a response, the exception is thrown before

Comment: No difference when I run it as administrator

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem was a missing cipher 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256' (due to security rules.....)

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, issuing the same query with curl is working without any problem:

```
curl --tlsv1.2 -v \
  --cacert ca_crt.pem \
  --cert cert.pem \
  --key key.pem \
  https://yyyyyyyy:8081/xxxxxxxxx
```

And the following cipher suite is used:

```
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```